# What is meant by “l'esprit de l'escalier”?

Tags: expressions, sens

What is meant by “*the spirit of the staircase*”?

Comment: Thanks, your question (or should I say its answers) taught me something today. French is my mother tongue, but I didn't know that expression.

Comment: @Oltarus Glad to be of service :)

Comment: "Staircase wit" does exist in English and oten uses a German loanword (itself a literal translation of Rousseau's expression): *Treppenwitz*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here, *esprit* means wit, not spirit or mind. *Avoir de l'esprit* means being skilled at repartee. In a related meaning, *l'esprit de [quelque chose]* is a mental attitude that highlights said thing in some fashion, for example *un esprit de décision* characterises someone who is good (and, especially, quick) at decision-making. *L'esprit de l'escalier* is a kind of wit that comes when you're in the staircase on your way out from a meeting with someone, and just now realize what you should have said five minutes ago. It's as though the staircase was a necessary factor in your being witty: it is a wit of the staircase. Thus, *faire preuve d'esprit de l'escalier* means finding the right repartee too late. *Avoir l'esprit de l'escalier* means doing this habitually.

[This expression has a known specific origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier): the essay [*Paradoxe sur le comédien*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxe_sur_le_com%C3%A9dien) by [Denis Diderot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denis_Diderot), in which the author describes this phenomenon:

> This negative remark disconcerted me and reduced me to silence. For the sensible man that I am is fully engrossed in the objection just received and loses his head, to find it only once he has reached the bottom of the staircase.

The phrasing *esprit de l'escalier* is sometimes attributed to [Jean-Jacques Rousseau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Jacques_Rousseau), but [he does not seem to have used the phrase](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-l-esprit-de-l-escalier.php). Indeed that phrase [did not come into common use until the late 19th century](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=esprit+de+l+%27+escalier%2Cpour+comparaison&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 6):

Un esprit de repartie à retardement, qui ne trouve la bonne formule qu'après qu'elle a été utile (dans l'escalier après avoir quitté l'interlocuteur, d'après l'image).

Comment: Haha, je connaissais pas l'expression, mais ça me décrit très bien. Et finalement je me sens en bonne compagnie avec [Diderot et Rousseau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'esprit_de_l'escalier) ! :)

Comment: @Sam Grâce à ta correction, j'ai au moins appris que [repartie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/repartie) ne prend pas d'accent — j'aurais pourtant juré que si. Merci !