# What is the distinction between "l'esprit de l'escalier" and "l'esprit d'escalier"?

Tags: expressions

[English wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27esprit_de_l%27escalier) lists two variations right from the beginning: **l'esprit de l'escalier** and **l'esprit d'escalier**.

I understand that the full(er) phrase, **avoir l'esprit de l'escalier**, is attributed to Denis Diderot, and reads/sounds like the most formal.

On the other hand, the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/esprit_de_l%27escalier) lists simply **esprit de l'escalier**; and it seems that an even briefer **esprit d'escalier** [is passable](http://wordsmith.org/words/esprit_d_escalier.html).

"The spirit of the stairways" is such a great expression, and I would love to better understand the distinctions in usage. (Is it mostly formal vs. casual?)

Merci!

Comment: Personally, I think it is a very rare expression: I think I have never heard it used in spoken speech, only in literature or rather "high-quality" articles. My bet is that if you used it with the man on the street in France, he would probably not understand that phrase...

Comment: @Greg I often hear "long(ue) à la détente" instead from native French speakers in casual speech.

Comment: @alone-zee: true, this is very common, but *long à la détente* has a far broader meaning, it rather means "slow to react or to understand" in general, not just slow to find a retort. Ex: *J'ai du lui expliquer trois fois en détail. Il est long à la détente...*

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/what-is-meant-by-lesprit-de-lescalier

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a formal-vs-casual distinction per se between the two here. But again, I'd say (and I have no source for this, mind you) that the expression lost its "l'" over time. To my modern French ear, "L'esprit de l'escalier" sounds precisely like what a learned man might have said in Diderot's time. My guess would be that the elision occurred through general laziness. But I don't think people today would use one or the other to sound more (or less) formal. In fact, I've never heard anything else than "esprit d'escalier" but I have read the other version a few times.

Answer (score 2):

*L'esprit de l'escalier* is the original form, *l'esprit d'escalier* is more modern (some would say less correct).

*L'esprit de l'escalier* could also be understood as its litteral meaning: a spirit that would haunt the stairs. This confusion is not possible with the modern form.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" form is indeed ***(avoir) l'esprit de l'escalier*** which translates to "**staircase wit**". It is seldom used is everyday's conversation outside by cultured, literary oriented people (e.g. French teachers, theater comedians, authors, critics...)

My first impression would have been that ***esprit d'escalier*** is incorrect but this isn't the case as this simplified form is listed in dictionaries. The latter is getting more and more popular but I would still recommend the original form.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"L'esprit d'escalier" is the most commonly used form.Never heard "de l'escalier".